# Active device count on bigquery is significantly different than Google play console

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get current device count for android for different app versions. Here is my code so far:

```
with not_removed as (
select distinct user_pseudo_id as total_distinct_users
FROM table_name 
where event_name not in ("app_remove")
)

,
demo as
(SELECT 
          user_pseudo_id,
          app_info_version,
          operating_system
          
          
FROM churn_analysis.user_demographics
where user_pseudo_id in (select * from not_removed)
)

select app_info_version ,count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as launched_users
from demo
where operating_system='Android'
group by app_info_version
order by launched_users desc
```

This is giving a significantly different result than the stats shown on Google play store. Any thoughts please?

**update:** I am now using the following code, which is more logically sound, but there is still a 100k different in the stats from google play console.

```
with removed as 
(
select distinct user_pseudo_id as total_distinct_users
FROM `table_name` 
where event_name in ("app_remove")

)
,

not_removed as (
select distinct user_pseudo_id as total_distinct_users
FROM `table_name` 
where user_pseudo_id not in (select * from removed)
)

,
demo as
(SELECT 
          user_pseudo_id,
          app_info_version,
          operating_system
          
          
FROM churn_analysis.user_demographics
where user_pseudo_id in (select * from not_removed)
)

select app_info_version ,count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as launched_users
from demo
where operating_system='Android'
group by app_info_version
order by launched_users desc
```

Comment: I'm guessing that at least one issue is your not_removed CTE code. I'm assuming you're looking for user_pseudo_ids which don't have a app_removed event - but all you are doing is excluding the app_removed event record, not all records for users with that event. You probably want a NOT EXISTS correlated subquery instead

Comment: @NickW yes thanks, I have fixed that, and updated the question with new code, but still a significant difference exists.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, technically, with your latest code but as I don't know what stats you are looking at in Google Play or how they are calculated I can't really comment any further. All I can suggest is that you analyse your data and try to work out what's causing the differences. For example, if your figures are greater than Google's then you know that your filtering isn't restrictive enough, so what records are you including that Google isn't?